# how to run command on linux server forever

Tags: linux, server, centos, command

Sorry, I'm newbie to this "linux server" stuff.

so my command is something like this:

```
while true; do sleep 2; curl -F id="http://YOURDOMAIN" -F scrape=true -F access_token='YOURACCESSTOKEN' -F appID=FACEBOOKAPPID https://graph.facebook.com; done &
```

I want it to run infinitely on my ""Centos 8 server"" .

thanx in advance

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. YOu have code that looks like it should work. See below for further comments.
 . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: Which you then would run from a crontab entry, something like `0/5 * * * * /path/to/myScript > /tmp/myScriptsLogFile.txt 2>&1`. Search here for `crontab` and get some ideas on how to do that. OK, That's all I've got time for now. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter , this code should refresh a website every 2 seconds. I've used Putty to implement it ,but when I close PUTTY the session end ,also my website refreshment (reloading) stops.

Answer (score 0):

Add your command to a script say **cmd.sh** and run it in background.
**nohup sh cmd.sh &**
Here,
& is for background run and nohup will store all the std out from the script running in the background.

Comment: ok, could u tell me how I'm gonna do it on a linux server (Centos 8) ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use any text editor like vi/vim editor in your centos server to edit. Copy your command and paste into a file say cmd.sh using the editor and then run the **nohup sh cmd.sh &** command
If you don't know about vi editor follow below command

1. Copy the command
2. vi cmd.sh
3. Type "i" to enter insert mode
4. Click "shift + insert" to paste
5. Click "esc" key then ":wq"
6. nohup sh cmd.sh &
   Your std out wil be kn nohup.out file in the same directory